# css unable to select span element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an html with span element

```
<span>Skip to content</span>
```

I have many such span elements.

I am trying to hide them:

```
span {display: none;}
```

it does not select aything. and hide them

Comment: your code is work:http://jsfiddle.net/GxyL5/1/

Comment: maybe you not attaching stylesheet file to your html document. try `<span style="display:none">skip to content </span>` and check result

Comment: provide a fiddle to get more response

Comment: <span style="display: none">skip to content</span> added in the html but does not work. the element does not get hide

Comment: sorry it started working, actually there was another rule of display with class selector which took precendence.

Answer (score 1):

This is really odd. Try with `span {display: none !important;}` just in case something else is overriding your styles.

If that does not help, try

```
<span style="display:none !important;">Skip to content</span>
```